# Stuck with TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, numpy

I have field stored as object in my df, and I'm trying to replace low frequency values with 'other' with the following code:

```
cols = ['Keyword']

for col in cols:
    val = df_ch[col].value_counts()
    y = val[val < 10000].index

df_ch[col] = df_ch[col].replace({x:'other' for x in y})
```

But I'm keeping having this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'str'
```

What am I missing?

This is how the filed looks like:

```
df_ch['Keyword'].head(20)
Out[55]: 
0                 (not provie)
1                 (not provie)
2                    (not set)
3                    (not set)
4                 (not provie)
5                 (not provie)
6                    (not set)
7                    (not set)
8                     keyword1
9                 (not provie)
10                   (not set)
11                   (not set)
12                (not provie)
13                (not provie)
14                   (not set)
15                (not provie)
16                (not provie)
17                     display
18                (not provie)
19                (not provie)
Name: Keyword, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to replace the group names with `Other` if their count is less than a certain number.

In your method, the usage of the [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function is wrong. In this case, you should pass a dictionary as an input, that has the column-value mapping:

```
df_ch.replace({'Keyword': {x:'other' for x in y}}, inplace=True)
```

---

Here's another approach without a loop

First count the numbers

```
x = df_ch['Keyword'].value_counts().reset_index()
#     index          0
#0  (not provie)    11
#1  (not set)        7
#2  keyword1         1
#3  display          1
```

Then assign `Other` to groups that have counts below a certain threshold (5 here).

```
df_ch.loc[df_ch['Keyword'].isin(x['index'].loc[x['Keyword']<5]), 'Keyword']='Other'
df_ch['Keyword']


0   (not provie)
1   (not provie)
2   (not set)
3   (not set)
4   (not provie)
5   (not provie)
6   (not set)
7   (not set)
8   Other
9   (not provie)
10  (not set)
11  (not set)
12  (not provie)
13  (not provie)
14  (not set)
15  (not provie)
16  (not provie)
17  Other
18  (not provie)
19  (not provie)
```